# Eficiencia, no repetir código

Tags: c#, .net

Quisiera evitar la repetición del siguiente código, mi aplicación hace un efecto de fadeout (fundido de salida) cuando cierran la aplicación, y también lo hace a la hora de abrir un nuevo form. (El primero se cierra y se abre el segundo form).

Tengo un timer con el siguiente código:

```
    private void FadeOut_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e){

        if (this.Opacity > 0)
        {
            this.Opacity = this.Opacity - 0.050;
        }
        else
        {
            FadeOut.Stop();
            this.Close();
        }
    }
```

En el evento closing simplemente inicio el Timer con un `Fadeout.Start();`

El problema está en que, al abrir el segundo form, yo no quiero cerrar el primero, sino esconderlo con el método hide. Por lo que tendría que hacer otro timer que en lugar de cerrar la aplicación `this.Close()` la ocultara `this.Hide()`.

¿Cómo reutilizarías el código de manera que no se repita y no sea necesario hacer dos timers? Se me ocurre hacer un método y pasarle algún parámetro y en función de eso haga `Hide` or `close`, pero no sé hasta que punto eso sea más eficiente que simplemente repetir código.

Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La manera mas sencilla de reutilizar código en todos los formularios es creando una clase base, para este caso en la clase base necesitas sobrecargar el evento `OnFormClosing` y `SetVisibleCore`
 para poder agregarle el FadeOut.
para este ejemplo no use Timer si no `Task.Delay`:

```
public class FormBase : Form
{
    private async Task FadeOut(int interval = 50)
    {
        while (Opacity > 0.0)
        {
            await Task.Delay(interval);
            Opacity -= 0.05;
        }
        Opacity = 0;
    }
    private async Task FadeIn(int interval = 50)
    {
        while (Opacity < 1.0)
        {
            await Task.Delay(interval);
            Opacity += 0.05;
        }
        Opacity = 1;
    }
    protected override async void OnFormClosing(FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Opacity > 0)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
            await FadeOut();
            Close();
        }
    }


    protected override async void SetVisibleCore(bool value)
    {
        if (value)
        {
            base.SetVisibleCore(value);
            await FadeIn();
        }
        else
        {
            await FadeOut();
            base.SetVisibleCore(value);
        }
    }
}
```

Con esto tendrías centralizado en una sola clase la lógica del fadeOut y fadeIn, al momento de Implementar un nuevo formulario en vez que herede de `Form` lo heredas de `FormBase` y listo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Este problema en el fondo es la composición de los siguientes problemas:

Problema 1. Hacer el manejador genérico:

Para ello hay muchas alternativas, ninguna de ellas extremadamente sencilla. Queremos simular el paso de un parámetro al manejador y los parámetros son pasados por el emisor del evento, así que no hay una forma limpia de aportarlos mediante los eventArgs.

Sin embargo,

1.a. puedes hacer una clase que contenga como atributo un flag que sea la operación mostrar u ocultar e implementar algo parecido a lo que propone Dariel Ramos Díaz de Villegas

1.b. Puedes crear una expresión lambda que genere una expresión lambda para mostrar u ocultar en función del parámetro de la primera.

Problema 2. Reutilizar el timer

Para reutilizar el timer, recuerda que el evento Tick del timer es eso, un evento. Admite múltiples manejadores. Tan solo asígnale el manejador de abrir, el de cerrar, ambos o ninguno para abrir, cerrar, abrir y cerrar (dos formularios distintos) o no hacer nada en absoluto (aunque para no hacer nada en absoluto puedes deshabilitar el timer).

Si deseas una implementación de lo que propongo, comenta mi respuesta pidiéndolo y así lo haré.

Con esto considero que he respondido a la pregunta, pero me parece muy importante mencionar lo siguiente:

**La eficiencia no consiste en esto**. Tu código no va a ser más eficiente o menos eficiente por usar un timer en vez de dos. Como tampoco lo va a ser por el número de líneas de código de tu código fuente (de hecho hay técnicas que incrementan la longitud del código pero lo hacen más eficiente). El código es reutilizado por motivos de mantenibilidad, no por eficiencia.

Considera que estás escribiendo código en un lenguaje de alto nivel. Dado que estás usando .Net, tú código es transformado a un código intermedio en un lenguaje conocido como CIL. A su vez, este código es transformado de nuevo por el CLR en código nativo.

Con esto en mente, observa que un timer es en el fondo una representación abstracta para poder desencadenar un evento periódicamente. Tener dos timers significa ocupar algunos bytes más en memoria y tener los dos timers activos implica realizar desencadenar dos eventos en vez de uno, pero la diferencia entre tener dos timers con un manejador en cada uno y tener un timer con dos manejadores es despreciable (tan despreciable que te animo a que hagas la media de mil ejecuciones de mil ciclos por cada alternativa, verás que, a lo sumo, hay unos pocos milisegundos de diferencia).

No voy a tratar en detalle el tema de las optimizaciones de código porque es muy (pero que muy) amplio, pero si tu idea es optimizar el código, no van por ahí los tiros. Es mucho más importante tener en cuenta los mecanismos de caché y el  acceso a bases de datos (por ejemplo) que la reutilización de una variable.

Un saludo y siéntete libre de preguntar lo que quieras.